# Open Word from Excel in write mode

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to edit a .docx file from excel(vba).

My code so far:

```
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

Set wApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.docx", ReadOnly:=False)
```

The thing is that the word file opens correctly, but it opens as read only file and i need to edit its text.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the Word document saved as a read only file?

Comment: Nope, the document is not read only

Comment: Nah, i got it already. The whole system was stored in a read only folder. Shame on me.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Is the file Word document downloaded, or did you write it?

Comment: You can use `FileCopy` to move the file out of the Read-Only system and `SetAttr filePath, vbNormal` to make the file Read-Write